# Animate a StackedBarChart without changing its range

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

**Task**

I have to create with JavaFX a bar that is splitted in multiple part, where each part represent one type of data. Some CheckBox allow the user to choose the type of data he want to display.

I used a StackedBarChart, and when I hide all the mark it looks like what I wanted.

However, I need it to be animated when I change the data.

**Problem**

I wanted to fix the size of the bar, so I set the upperbound to 100 and I did some math to split my data in percentage. It works, but by doing that, I have a fixed range for my chart, and because of that fixed range, I've lost the automatic animation of the chart.

The animation I need is that, when I remove or add a type of data, the sub-bar grow progressively to fill the blank space or decrease to let the new sub-bar appear.

I've tried to clear my chart at each change, but the animation I get this way is not what I want.

Here is the FXML of my bar (I have also tried to set autoranging to true, but no result, which is normal since my range is fixed anyway):

```
<StackedBarChart fx:id="stackedBar" 
        horizontalGridLinesVisible="false" horizontalZeroLineVisible="false"
        verticalGridLinesVisible="false" verticalZeroLineVisible="false"
        legendVisible="false"
        minHeight="20" maxHeight="100" 
        >
            <xAxis>
                <NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" side="BOTTOM" autoRanging="false"  lowerBound="0"  opacity="0"/>
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <CategoryAxis side="LEFT" opacity="0" />
            </yAxis>
        </StackedBarChart>
```

and here is the Java Code where I put the data in my chart

```
    //stackedBar.getData().clear();


    //((NumberAxis)stackedBar.getXAxis()).setUpperBound(80);

    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, String>> stackedBarData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie1 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
    serie1.setName(strNouvelle);
    serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageNouvelle, "actions"));

    StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie2 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
    serie2.setName(strEnCours);
    serie2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageEnCours, "actions"));

    StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie3 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
    serie3.setName(strTermine);
    serie3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageTermine, "actions"));

    StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie4 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
    serie4.setName(strRefuse);
    serie4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageRefuse, "actions"));

    StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie5 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
    serie5.setName(strHorsDelais);
    serie5.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageHorsDelais, "actions"));

    stackedBarData.addAll(serie1,serie2, serie3, serie4, serie5);
    stackedBar.setData(stackedBarData);

    ((NumberAxis)stackedBar.getXAxis()).setUpperBound(100);
```

Thank you in advance ! and sorry for my english, i'm not a native speaker ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it : I just had to modify the data already in the chart instead of reset it like I did.

It looks like that now :

```
if (stackedBar.getData().isEmpty()) 
    {
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, String>> stackedBarData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie1 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
        serie1.setName(strNouvelle);
        serie1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageNouvelle, "actions"));

        StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie2 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
        serie2.setName(strEnCours);
        serie2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageEnCours, "actions"));

        StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie3 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
        serie3.setName(strTermine);
        serie3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageTermine, "actions"));

        StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie4 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
        serie4.setName(strRefuse);
        serie4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageRefuse, "actions"));

        StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String> serie5 = new StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>();
        serie5.setName(strHorsDelais);
        serie5.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageHorsDelais, "actions"));

        stackedBarData.addAll(serie1,serie2, serie3, serie4, serie5);
        stackedBar.setData(stackedBarData);
    }
    else
    {
        ((StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>)stackedBar.getData().get(0)).getData().set(0, new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageNouvelle, "actions"));
        ((StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>)stackedBar.getData().get(1)).getData().set(0, new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageEnCours, "actions"));
        ((StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>)stackedBar.getData().get(2)).getData().set(0, new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageTermine, "actions"));
        ((StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>)stackedBar.getData().get(3)).getData().set(0, new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageRefuse, "actions"));
        ((StackedBarChart.Series<Number, String>)stackedBar.getData().get(4)).getData().set(0, new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(pourcentageHorsDelais, "actions"));
    }
```